# When should you wrap include in `extern "C"` when including a C Library

Tags: c++

I understand that when you include a `c` header in your `c++` project you must wrap it with `extern "C"` because `c++` and `c` have two different ways of identifying function. `c` will use the name to identify a function and `c++` must use the name and the parameters to satisfy function overloading.

What I don't understand is why are there are `c` headers that don't require to be wrapped in `extern "C"` like `windows.h`??

Comment: `windows.h` is *not* a library.  It is a header file, and a header is not a library.

Comment: @WilliamPursell By a library I did mean header file. But with your logic, you can't include a library in C++ compilation file anyways.

Comment: You are correct, it is not possible to include a library.  You can include a header file, and you can link against a library.  The two ought not be confused.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, wrapping a C header in `extern "C"` is not a good idea. The header might include other files that break when you do this. A C header that is **designed** to be used in C++ will handle `extern "C"` appropriately, without you having to do anything. Typical code:

```
#ifndef MY_HEADER_INCLUDE_GUARD
#define MY_HEADER_INCLUDE_GUARD

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* C callable stuff goes here */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* MY_HEADER_INCLUDE_GUARD */
```

Comment: The header might also define a struct with a member named `class` or a macro named `string`.  (I've actually encountered both.)

Comment: But when you include headers like `lua` then you wrap it with `extern "C"`, why did they not plan for that?

Comment: @Caesar: if a *particular* C header tells you that you can include it in C++, but must provide the `extern "C" {` ... `}` yourself, then of course you should do as you're told. But the reason there are headers for which you don't have to do this is precisely what Pete says in this answer: because those headers have been designed for use in both C and C++.

Comment: I always thought it was because the makers of lua believe in segregation