# Add Another C Source and Header on NDK Project

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have added a simple header and c file in jni folder.

```
-jni
   -calculate.c
   -calculate.h
   -HelloJNI.cpp
   -Android.MK
```

Here's the code.
a. calculate.h

```
int add(int x, int y);
int minus(int x, int y);
```

b. calculate.c

```
#include "calculate.h"

/**
 * Implementation add
 */
int add(int x, int y){
    return x + y;
}

/**
 * Implementation minus
 */
int minus(int x, int y){
    return x - y;
}
```

c.HelloJNI.cpp

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "calculate.h"

extern "C" {
     JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_farissyariati_hellojni_MainActivity_stringFromJni(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj);
};

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_farissyariati_hellojni_MainActivity_stringFromJni(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj){
    //Calculate *myCalculate = new Calculate();
    //int result = myCalculate->add(10,20);
    int res = add(10, 20);
    return env->NewStringUTF("Hello From CPP");
}
```

Before adding this code:
int res = add(10, 20);

the application run as expected. Suppose, I have to add something in Android.mk what should I add for it? Here is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := HelloJNI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := HelloJNI.cpp
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

UPDATE.

I change my Android.mk like this, but still not working.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_SRC_FILE = /Users/farissyariati/Documents/EclipseProjects/HelloJNI/jni

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := HelloJNI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := HelloJNI.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(MY_SRC_FILE)/calculate/
LOCAL_SRC_FILES  += $(MY_SRC_FILE)/calculate/calculate.c
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify more than one source file on a single line, like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := HelloJNI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := HelloJNI.cpp calculate.c
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

However since you are calling C code from C++, you will need to use extern "C" to specify C-style linkage. You can wrap the #include like this (in HelloJNI.cpp):

```
extern "C" {
    #include "calculate.h"
}
```

Alternatively, you can change calculate.h to handle linking with C++ code as shown in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778390/when-should-you-wrap-include-in-extern-c-when-including-a-c-library).